# How to reset incrementing variable after reaching numerical value in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating an extremely simple page, where the background and text color will change through 6 'themes' when the user clicks the page. I want the loop below to reset back to 1, after reaching 6. I know this is a bad way to do this, but since it doesn't need to scale, i dont care.

I tried to reset clicks = 1 within if (clicks > 6) and then exiting the scope with return, but i am still having scope issues. That seemed to follow some examples online, and i can't see what i am missing. it seems like ti would be really simple to do this.

```
<script>
    var clicks = 1;
    $('.foo').click(function() {
        if (clicks == 1){
            $('body, #change' ).addClass('pagetheme1');
            $('p' ).addClass('pagetheme1');
        } else if (clicks == 2){
            $('body, #change' ).addClass('pagetheme2');
            $('p' ).addClass('pagetheme2');
            $('body, #change' ).removeClass('pagetheme1');
            $('p' ).removeClass('pagetheme1');
        } else if (clicks == 3){
            $('body, #change' ).addClass('pagetheme3');
            $('p' ).addClass('pagetheme3');
            $('body, #change' ).removeClass('pagetheme2');
            $('p' ).removeClass('pagetheme2');
        } else if (clicks == 4){
            $('body, #change' ).addClass('pagetheme4');
            $('p' ).addClass('pagetheme4');
            $('body, #change' ).removeClass('pagetheme3');
            $('p' ).removeClass('pagetheme3');
        } else if (clicks == 5){
            $('body, #change' ).addClass('pagetheme5');
            $('p' ).addClass('pagetheme5');
            $('body, #change' ).removeClass('pagetheme4');
            $('p' ).removeClass('pagetheme4');
        } else if (clicks == 6){
            $('body, #change' ).addClass('pagetheme6');
            $('p' ).addClass('pagetheme6');
            $('body, #change' ).removeClass('pagetheme5');
            $('p' ).removeClass('pagetheme5');
            clicks=1;
        }
        }
        ++clicks;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You are incrementing after you set clicks=1. Also, you have an extra closing bracket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the modulo operator

```
var clicks = 0;
$('.foo').click(function() {
    // ...
    clicks = (clicks + 1) % 7;
});
```

This works by giving you the remainder of (clicks+1) divided by 7, which is clicks+1 when clicks is 0-5, or 0 when clicks=6.

Comment: Oh I like this. Very succinct. May you perhaps explain what the modulo operator does on the off chance the OP is unfamiliar with its use?